# capacity to read vs capacity for/of reading - preposition and verb tense choice

Tags: prepositions

Are the following sentences correct? Is there any difference in meaning? Are they equally usual?

> - She lost her capacity/ability **to read**.
> - She lost her capacity/ability **of reading**.
> - She lost her capacity/ability **for reading**.

Answer (score -1):

All of these are correct and meaning-equivalent:

> She lost her capacity to read.
>
> She lost her ability to read.
>
> She lost her capacity for reading.

Do not use `of` with `capacity` unless you mean it in the sense of "the maximum amount that something can contain" or "the maximum amount something can produce".

Do not use `of` or `for` with `ability`.

Comment: (I think "ability for" may have some usage in some places  -  but it's certainly not as common as the others I give)

Comment: Would the preposition choice be the same for the synonym "capability" ? Ex: She lost her capability for reading/of reading/to read.

Comment: I'd prefer the infinitive: "`She lost her capability to read`"  If using `of` with participle, I'd probably not use the possessive:  "`She lost the capability of reading`"  but would probably prefer "`She became incapable of reading`"   I would never say "`She lost her capability for reading`", but I think there may be some use of this, just as for `ability` above.  I might say "`She has some capability for reading`", but would probably prefer "`She has some capability in reading`" or "`She has some reading capability`"